# Summation Inequality: Intuitively Simple, but can't prove

Tags: proof-verification, summation, proof-writing

I have $n$ values of $z>0$ $Z$ = {$z_i,..,z_n$}.

$S$ is defined as a specific sum of all values in $Z$:

$$S=\sum_i(z_i)^c ,   c>1$$

Now we have a new sum $S'$ in which the first two values of $Z$ $z_1$ and $z_2$ are added together in the following way

$$S'=(z_1+z_2)^c+\sum_{i\neq1\neq2}(z_i)^c, c>1$$

Now, it seems intuitive that $S'>S$. What I'm trying to figure out how to is to prove this concisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$S=(z_1)^c+(z_2)^c+\sum_\limits{i\neq1\neq2}(z_i)^c$$

So $$S'-S=(z_1+z_2)^c-(z_1)^c-(z_2)^c\ge(z_1+z_2)(z_1+z_2)^{c-1}-(z_1)^c-(z_2)^c$$

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to prove is $(z_1+z_2)^c > z_1^c + z_2^c$ for $c>1$. Dividing through by $z_1$, it suffices to show that $(1+x)^c > 1 + x^c$ for $x>0$. We have

$$ (1+x)^c - 1 = \int_0^x c(1+t)^{c-1} \, dt > \int_0^x ct^{c-1} \, dt = x^c, $$
since $1+t>t$ everywhere on the interval.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Your problem is reducible to a problem to prove:

$$(a+b)^c>(a^c+b^c)\text{ for } c>1;a,b>0$$

Can you pick up from here?