# Inequality $2(x^p+y^p)^{1/p} \le x+y$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Is it true that $2(x^p+y^p)^{1/p} \le x+y$ for all $x,y \in [0,+\infty)$ where $p \in [1,+\infty)$?
I would like to add something to this question, but I really have no idea how to deal with this inequality.
Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT ok it clearly is not true if for example $x=0$ and $y=1$, but then for which values of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ this inequality holds?

Comment: Quite likely not for many cases, given that $$\frac{a^p +b^p}{2}\geq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^p$$ for $p\geq2$. $f(x)=x^p$ is convex.

Comment: And it's also false for $p=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (almost) looking at what is called a power mean or generalized mean. For these beasts, there exists the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality)   which holds for all *real* $p \ge 1$.
$$
\Big(\frac{x^p+y^p}{2}\Big)^{1/p} \color{red}{\ge} \frac{x+y}{2} 
$$
in a well-defined sense: the inequality becomes an equality if and only if $x=y$, or (trivial) $p=1$.

Use this to write $$
\leftrightarrow  2(x^p+y^p)^{1/p}  \ge 2^{1/p} (x+y) > x+y
$$

So your LHS will *never* be smaller than the RHS, but larger.

If you want an *upper bound*, you can of course write $2(x^p+y^p)^{1/p}  \le 2 (x+y)$. This is equivalent to $ (1+ \frac{y}{x})^p > 1+ (\frac{y}{x})^p$ and an elegant proof for this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2472034/317854): $ (1+a)^p - 1 = \int_0^a p(1+t)^{p-1} \, dt > \int_0^a pt^{p-1} \, dt = a^p$